# Insert https certificate on wildfly 18

Tags: java, spring, https, ssl-certificate, wildfly

I have to do a rest call and get a json from it, the call is made in https and when i do on postman or browser i can easly get the response json, the problem is when i do it on java i get this exception:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I followed few guide online and i was able to download the certificate from chrome and add it in the jdk-11, but the problem persist so i had to add my file.crt in the wildfly 18 keystore, but I still getting the same error, so does anybody knows how to solve it?

(the call i make it came from a server under apache)